# Wrong scroll position with estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm building a chat using `UITableView`. Naturally, the row heights of each chat message cell will vary widely. I've correctly calculated the row height for each cell and the Table View performs as it should.

However, I want to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` to speed up performance in case of many messages. The problem with this is that it affects the scrolling behaviour of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:Animated:`.

In my `viewWillAppear` life cycle method I tell the Table View to scroll down to the latest message (i.e. the bottom message), which performs well if I don't use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`, but as soon as I do it seems as if only the value returned from this method is used to calculate the scroll position and I end up in the wrong position.

Is it possible to benefit from the efficiency gains of using `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` without it affecting scroll behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so the method

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

of `UIScrollView` may help you to achieve what you want

Comment: In my case, for this method to work properly I would have to calculate the combined height of all the rows in my table view right? Isn't that just as expensive as using `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` without `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Yes you're right. But I think as long as you need to scroll programmatically the calculation can't be bypassed. Whether calculate in `scrollRectToVisible` yourself or in `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` by system.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of. Guys I have to figure out a way to make that calculation as efficient as possible :)